# What's the best way to view lines X through Y of a large file?

Tags: tail, head

I have a very large text file and I want to view, say, lines 2000 through 2010 (with the line numbers included)

I know one sort of roundabout way of getting there:

```
sc -l [file]
cat -n [file] | tail -n [previous result - 2000] | head -n 10
```

But it feels like there must be a better way. Is there?

Comment: Your last command can be simplified to head -2010 FileName | tail -10.

Comment: @amit_g: Ha, good call. Somehow I totally missed that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sed` if you know the lines you want.

`sed -n X,Yp file.txt`

Or if it's stuff between some REGEX, with `awk`:

`awk '/FIRST REGEX/,/LAST REGEX/' input.txt`

Or an `awk` way of doing the sed suggestion:

`awk 'NR>=X && NR<=Y' file.txt`

Comment: +1 `sed` is a good choice.  It can do regex ranges as well, e.g., `sed -n '/^#ifdef/,/^#endif/p'`.